# Tell the user which Google account is being used when creating a new site account

Tags: feature-request, login

I recently created a new account on a Stack Exchange site ([Bicycles.SE](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com)). I chose to do so using Google, through which I have two accounts, one for personal use and one for work. I always create Stack Exchange accounts on new sites via my personal account.

However, when I was creating a new account, I saw this:

[image: Google]

All I am told is that it is "a login from Google". Is it my personal account or my work account? I have absolutely no way of knowing.

What I want is for it to clearly tell me which Google account is being used. Simply having the username and/or e-mail address would be perfectly sufficient. Something like this:

[image]

This clearly tells me which account I am using, and helps me avoid a situation in which I would create an account on a new site using the wrong e-mail account.

Comment: Well, you can go to mail.google.com and you'll see there - but agree it should be also added to the login page of SE itself.

Comment: I think SE cannot detect which account you want to use.If you go to next step google will ask you which one you want to use.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam, Google did not prompt me when I clicked "Confirm and Create this Account", probably because I wasn't logged into both at the time. But which was I logged into? Without going to another site, I couldn't have known.

Comment: I'm logged into multiple accounts and it didn't say anything about which account it was using or ask me which account to use. This needs to be fixed.

Comment: Still not fixed...