# "Confirm new account" dialog lacks reference to my network account

Tags: support, user-accounts, google-chrome

I believe I have a Stack Overflow account associated with a (non-Google) email.

I am logged in to this account. I am using Google Chrome, which itself is apparently logged into a Google account.

When I visit a new Stack Exchange property, I am presented with this dialog:

[image: google confirm new account dialog]

I would read this as "I am going to create you an (unrelated) account associated with your Gmail address", not as "Hi, @FauxFaux, I know who you are! Let's join this site."

I find this confusing enough to write it down.

---

It appears I do actually have Chrome's Gmail address associated with the Stack Exchange account, and it does happen to do the right thing (associated the new Meta account with the existing Stack Exchange account).

If you are not logged into Chrome, it shows "login from Stack Exchange", which would not have caused me this deep, deep agony.

Comment: `"I would read this as "I am going to create you an (unrelated) account associated with ..."` - it's a "new" account on the site listed; you don't have an existing one there. - `"... and it does happen to do the right thing  ..."` (works, like it says it does. ---- then (are you asking?), `"... which would not have caused me this deep, deep agony."` - what "agony" logging in by using Stack Exchange instead of Google. --- Clearly state the problem or question. --- Suggest alternative wording if you think that the Dialog should have said something else.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261221/323179